# Transaction fee restrictions with solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, gas-price, payable

Can I restrict transaction fee (gas price) for the `payable` method of the crowdsale contract. And if I can, how?

And one more question, if I restrict fee and call `revert()` - this transaction will be declined in the memepool and will be not mined at all, or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to stop a transaction from being mined, but you can check the gas price using `tx.gasprice` and not process transactions that are above a certain gas price, e.g.

```
function() payable {
    require(tx.gasprice<30000000000); //30000000000 is 30 gwei
                                      //if gas price is higher than it, the tx will fail
    doOtherProcessing();
}
```

Note that this will refund any unused gas. If you change `require` to `assert`, then it wont refund the unused gas.

Comment: But even in this case transaction will be mined but as failed and sender spent gas for it?

Comment: Yes, the transaction will be mined and will fail due to a revert opcode. The sender will pay for the already-used gas.